# Powershell script for software automation using chocolatey

Tags: powershell, automation, chocolatey, interaction

Code for my chocolatey script:

```
$apps=@('googlechrome','firefox','codeblocks','windbg','nasm','explorersuite','pestudio','vscode','sysinternals','python','Google Earth')

function Show-Menu 
{    
    Clear-Host
    Write-Host "**********************************************"
    Write-Host "LIST OF SOFTWARES"

    # write the options using the array of packages

    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $apps.Count; $i++)
    {
        # {0,5} means right align with spaces to max 5 characters
        Write-Host ('{0,5}. {1}' -f ($i + 1), $apps[$i])
    }

    Write-Host " q. Exit the script"
    Write-Host "*************************************************"
    Write-Host
}

# Step 4) enter an endless loop you only exit if the user enters 'q'

while ($true)
{
    Show-Menu

    $UserInput = Read-Host "Enter the software number to be installed"

    # test if the user wants to quit and if so, break the loop

    if ($UserInput -eq 'q') 
    { 
            break 
    }

    # testing if the user entered a number between 1 and the total number of packages (inclusive)

    if ([int]::TryParse($UserInput,[ref]$null) -and 1..$apps.Count -contains [int]$UserInput)
    {
        # here you install the chosen package using the array index number (= user input number minus 1)
        $apps = [int]$UserInput - 1

        foreach($app in $apps) 
        {
            $result = Get-InstalledApps | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -like $app }

            if($result -eq $null) 
            {
                # get the index for the installer for this app
                $i = $apps.IndexOf($app)
                Write-Host "$app not found. Installing" $name[$i]

                (cinst $name[$i] -y)
            }
            else
            {

                $availableOptions = 1..$apps.Count -join ','
                Write-Host "Error in selection, choose $availableOptions or q" -Foreground Color Red
            }

            $null = Read-Host "Press Enter to continue"
        }

    }

}
```

When I run the script I am getting the following error message:

```
 Enter the software number to be installed: 11
 
 LIST OF SOFTWARES

     1. googlechrome
     2. firefox
     3. codeblocks
     4. windbg
     5. nasm
     6. explorersuite
     7. pestudio
     8. vscode
     9. sysinternals
    10. python
    11. Google Earth
  q. Exit the script
*************************************************

Enter the software number to be installed: 11
googlechrome not found. Installing googleearthpro
Chocolatey v0.11.1
Installing the following packages:
googleearthpro
By installing, you accept licenses for the packages.
googleearthpro v7.3.4 already installed.
 Use --force to reinstall, specify a version to install, or try upgrade.

Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Warnings:
 - googleearthpro - googleearthpro v7.3.4 already installed.
 Use --force to reinstall, specify a version to install, or try upgrade.
Press Enter to continue: 
firefox not found. Installing googlechrome
Chocolatey v0.11.1
Installing the following packages:
googlechrome
By installing, you accept licenses for the packages.
GoogleChrome v93.0.4577.63 already installed.
 Use --force to reinstall, specify a version to install, or try upgrade.

Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Warnings:
 - googlechrome - GoogleChrome v93.0.4577.63 already installed.
 Use --force to reinstall, specify a version to install, or try upgrade.
Press Enter to continue: 
codeblocks not found. Installing firefox
Chocolatey v0.11.1
Installing the following packages:
firefox
By installing, you accept licenses for the packages.
Firefox v91.0.2 already installed.
 Use --force to reinstall, specify a version to install, or try upgrade.

Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Warnings:
 - firefox - Firefox v91.0.2 already installed.
 Use --force to reinstall, specify a version to install, or try upgrade.
Press Enter to continue: 
windbg not found. Installing notepadplus
Chocolatey v0.11.1
Installing the following packages:
notepadplus
By installing, you accept licenses for the packages.
notepadplus not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.
 Source(s): 'https://community.chocolatey.org/api/v2/'
 NOTE: When you specify explicit sources, it overrides default sources.
If the package version is a prerelease and you didn't specify `--pre`,
 the package may not be found.
Please see https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/troubleshooting for more
 assistance.

Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures
 - notepadplus - notepadplus not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.
 Source(s): 'https://community.chocolatey.org/api/v2/'
 NOTE: When you specify explicit sources, it overrides default sources.
If the package version is a prerelease and you didn't specify `--pre`,
 the package may not be found.
Please see https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/troubleshooting for more
 assistance.
Press Enter to continue:
```

What needs to be fixed to make this work?

Comment: without seeing what choco commands you run, and not nowing the content of $apps, we won't really be able to help you.

Comment: $apps=@('googlechrome','firefox','codeblocks','windbg','nasm','explorersuite','pestudio','vscode','sysinternals','python','Google Earth')  and the choco command i am using is choco install

Comment: Oh dear... `$apps = [int]$UserInput - 1` returns the **index** number of the chosen app, so you should capture that in a variable `$index`. Now you are **overwriting** your array of apps.. Next you call a function `Get-InstalledApps` which is not defined and also really unneeded, since you know by then what the user wants to install, namely `$apps[$index]`. What is `cinst`?? shouldn't that be `choco`. You never said what version of chocolatey you're using. For the things you want, you need Chocolatey Pro..

Comment: sir tell me where the changes to be done in script so that i will do

Comment: `$apps = [int]$UserInput - 1` seems unneeded with the code that follows. It looks like you're using some kind of template so why not link the source of that? What needs to be fixed (as a first step) was already mentioned.

Comment: @Seth The OP tried to change the code I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68984703/9898643), but apparently did not fully grasp what it is doing. In comments, we've explained that only the Pro version of chocolately can skip installations when certain software is already installed (to some extent..) Otherwise, he will need to have choco install all the software from the list on a fresh computer and try to figure out if those packages can be spotted elsewhere (registry perhaps) together with their verion numbers. Then you can include PS logic to prevent installation where not needed.

Comment: sir if anything needs to changed in the above script to make it work please suggest sir

Comment: The above script is not working i tried so many times by changing but still not able to resolving please let me know where i am wrong .

Answer (score 0):

Currently the only error in your question is that `notepadplus` failed to install, with the reason:

```
The package was not found with the source(s) listed. Source(s): 'https://community.chocolatey.org/api/v2/'
```

You probably meant to install `notepadplusplus`?

https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/notepadplusplus

Comment: 1.Sir every time the menu is not suppose of if enter the corresponding number of the software then after installing that software again the menu has to be displayed 2. Second issue I am facing is when I enter the corresponding number of the software for example I enter 11 for google earth software to be installed but I am getting chrome not found why it is showing chrome not found . What mistake is their in my script.